# Why ACT led is blinking and raspberry not booting?

Tags: boot, raspbmc, led

I have a Raspberry Pi (Model B) with a 8GB SD card, and Rasbpmc installed.

Suddenly, one day, it not boot and have these symptoms:

- Red Led is ON
- Green Led (ACT) is blinking
- A rainbow screen is shown
- After this rainbow screen reboots

I've installed again the last rasbpmc distro in the SD card, but still have the same problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unplug everything including, network cable, wifi dongle mouse, keyboard. So only the video cable and the SD card are connected.

Not all SD cards are fully compatible with the Raspberry Pi.
http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards

Try the latest noobs install to confirm that it is the card or the Raspmc image at fault.
http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Comment: I've made these steps: 1 - Unplug all (except hdmi cable and power suply). 2 - Install NOOB at the SD card. When boot still happens the same problem

Comment: Either its the power supply, SD card or the Pi, test the power with the instructions here http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems